# Inserir String em gráfico primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou montando um gráfico, porém preciso exibir os dados de um campo que é "String", porém ele só receber inteiro.

Alguém ai já passou por isso?

```
tempo.set(u.formataData(treinos.get(i).getDataTreino()), 
u.formataHoraComSegundos(treinos.get(i).getTempoRealizado()));
```

Comment: Como é o gráfico que vc quer fazer? Pode mostrar um exemplo usando os dados que você tem? Poste também o código onde ficam esses dados.